# Files permission issue

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions

I'm using CENTOS 6.4 with the last version of APACHE.

I was trying to put some files in the "/var/www/html" directory in case i want to download them for my personal use.

I missed with one file's permission after putting it in the directory.
now i can access all the files but this one, although i have set its permission to be the same as another accessible file.

The output of `ls -l` of the two files:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 241172480 Mar  5 03:05 name_of_accessible_file
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4353378304 Mar  5 20:44 name_of_inaccessible_file
```

Can anyone explain what is that, and how to files having the same file permission and user and group owner treated differently.

`ls -lZ` output

-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 name_of_accessible_file

-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 name_of_inaccessible_file

and yes, SElinux set to enforcing.

Comment: Can you add the output of ls -lZ? Also, is SElinux set to enforcing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is an SELinux issue. To change it, you'll need to change the lable on the inaccessible file so Apache can work with it:

`restorecon -v /var/www/html/name_of_inaccessible_file`